# Unable to send email using PHPMailer connected with Tor. Getting SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses. How to fix this?

Tags: nginx, phpmailer, tor, darknet, deep-web

My team and I are willing to set an onion address for our website.

We can access the website and PHP is working well but we can't send emails through PHPMailer.

We use [danwin1210](https://danwin1210.me/mail/) as host server with the following configuration in our php file :

```
<?php
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
  require("tools/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
  require("tools/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php");
  require("tools/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php");

    if(!$error){
      try {
        $email = new PHPMailer;
        $email->isSMTP();
        $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
        $email->Host = 'danielas3rtn54uwmofdo3x2bsdifr47huasnmbgqzfrec5ubupvtpid.onion';
        $email->Port = 25;
        $email->SMTPAuth = true;
        $email->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
        $email->Username = "XXXXXX@tt3j2x4k5ycaa5zt.onion";
        $email->Password = "XXXXXX";
        $email->CharSet = 'utf-8';
        $email->setFrom('XXXXXX@tt3j2x4k5ycaa5zt.onion', 'XXXXXX');
        ...
```

Here is the error we get :

```
2019-11-18 15:16:38 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Can someone tell us if this is correct ? Do we need to change something here or in our servers' config files ?

Comment: This sounds like your DNS isn't resolving correctly, though that's possibly expected behaviour with Tor. If you can do the lookup outside this function and pass in an IP to connect to instead, it should work, assuming that your tor stack takes care of the rest. That said, SMTP over proxies is a bit difficult anyway, so I don't know how well this works, or whether it works at all.

Comment: Here is the result of '''dig''' on the host :
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> ygqevii2umdcvk5z4k2pqxhpynpgix63dl5prcslz4gggph5ea63qrqd.onion
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 46897
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ygqevii2umdcvk5z4k2pqxhpynpgix63dl5prcslz4gggph5ea63qrqd.onion. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
onion.   10800 IN SOA localhost. nobody.invalid. 1 3600 1200 604800 10800

Comment: But I'm able to reach google.com so my DNS is OK.

Comment: To connect to a Tor hidden service to send mail from PHPMailer, it would need to establish the connection through Tor's SOCKS proxy port. Unfortunately, PHPMailer doesn't support SOCKS so you'll either need to adapt their code to support it, or go a different route. PHP curl can do SMTP over SOCKS but you'll need to formulate the entire MIME message on your own to send.

Comment: Ok, so the best way is to configure my own mail server like explained [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13246/unix-command-mail-send-mail-to-an-onion-address-mail) ?

Comment: Kind of depends on how hidden you want to keep that box. If you don't care that mail sent from the site might expose it's network address from email headers, you can always send mail over the clear net. If the box is totally locked down and can only network over Tor. Maybe an easier route with PHPMailer would be to use `getSentMIMEMessage()` after calling preSend() to get the full message source and then use curl to send.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll use that. It seems working

Comment: I also have a PoC using PHPMailer + curl (which could then use Tor over SOCKS5). If you're interested in seeing it let me know.